# MacOS Ampps domain not redirecting to directory

Tags: macos, apache, ampps

I'm trying to add domain in Ampps. In the admin panel http://localhost/ampps I've added domain: devvape.

I've got directory in /Applications/Ampps/www/devvape/ but when I enter http://devvape It shows me /Applications/Ampps/www/ directory.

Any ideas why?

Heres my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName devvape
ServerAlias devvape
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/Ampps/www/devvape/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "/Applications/Ampps/www/devvape"
ErrorLog "/Applications/Ampps/apache/logs/devvape.pl.err"
CustomLog "/Applications/Ampps/apache/logs/devvape.pl.log" combined

    <Directory "/Applications/Ampps/www/devvape">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have the same problem